# screen.onkey using Shift key

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am writing some code in Python using screen.onkey from turtle. Is there any way to use the Shift key on your keyboard to trigger an event.

```
   import turtle
walk_speed=10
def sprint():
    global walk_speed
    walk_speed+=8
def slow():
    global walk_speed
    walk_speed-=8
screen.onkeypress(sprint, "Shift")
screen.onkeyrelease(slow, "Shift")
```

The program works fine with the space bar or a letter key assigned. Is there any way to use the shift key here?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is using the keyboard module.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to use `screen.onkeypress(sprint, "Shift")` You can ofcourse import a keyboard module. the final code:

```
import turtle
import keyboard
walk_speed=10
def sprint():
    global walk_speed
    walk_speed+=8
def slow():
    global walk_speed
    walk_speed-=8
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        sprint()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        slow()
```

Comment: What about Ctrl and Delete?